# Where is the last green star in the Clockwork Ruins Galaxy?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2

I have gotten all of the stars for the Clockwork Ruins Galaxy except for the last green star (the third one). I have searched everywhere for it and can't seem to find it. I feel it might be off the screen somewhere that I can't see. Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The player should replay the Time for Adventure mission. This time, the final Green Power Star is located on the Millstone Planet. The player needs to travel through the millstone planet until he or she reaches the part where the Power Star is. The player should see the Green Star off to the distance. The player must climb onto a millstone to head towards the star. Once the player is close enough, he or she should perform a somersault followed by a Star Spin to reach the Star.

[Source](http://www.mariowiki.com/Clockwork_Ruins_Galaxy#Green_Star_3)

Comment: Thaaanks Frank.

Comment: Mariowiki is awesome